# Sending a template parameter pack to std::basic_ostream

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, variadic-templates, ostream

There's a code example on a [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for `std::integer_sequence`:

```
template<typename T, T... ints>
void print_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...> int_seq)
{
    std::cout << "The sequence of size " << int_seq.size() << ": ";
    ((std::cout << ints << ' '),...);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I don't quite understand the `((std::cout << ints << ' '),...)` syntax. I don't see any overloaded versions of std::basic_ostream::operator<<` that would take a variadic template's parameter pack in.

What exactly is happening here, and how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't quite understand the `((std::cout << ints << ' '),...)` syntax. I don't see any overloaded versions of `std::basic_ostream::operator<<` that would take a variadic template's parameter pack in.
>
> What exactly is happening here, and how does it work?

If I'm not wrong, it's called ["fold expression"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) but you can find it also as "template folding" or simply "folding".

It's available starting from C++17.

The idea is apply an operator over a variadic pack of values.

Classic example: the sum.

If you want the sum of your `ints`, you can apply the `+` operator as follows

```
( ints + ... );
```

In your case, the fold expression is applied over the comma operator.

So, if `ints...` is (for example) `2, 3, 5, 7`, your expression:

```
((std::cout << ints << ' '),...);
```

is equivalent to

```
(std::cout << 2 << ' '), (std::cout << 3 << ' '), (std::cout << 5 << ' '), (std::cout << 7 << ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator<<` doesn't need to accept variadic parameter pack for this to work. What actually happens here is that, for example, for 3 integers that line will expand in something like this:

```cpp
(
  (std::cout << int1 << ' '),
  (std::cout << int2 << ' '),
  (std::cout << int3 << ' ')
);
```

Operator `,` guarantees left-to-right order of execution.